# No route matches controller in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, actioncontroller

I have an app where I'm creating a get action called "new_911". When I put new_911_call_path in the application layout I get an error "no route matches new_911 controller: calls".  Yet there is an action in the calls controller called new_911.  What am I doing wrong?

Calls Controller:

```
def new_911
    @call = Call.new :call_status => "open"
    respond_with @call
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<li><%= link_to 'New 911 Call', new_911_call_path %></li>
```

routes.rb

```
resources :calls do
    member do
      post 'close'
      post 'cancel'
      post 'note'
      get  'new_return'
      get 'duplicate_call'
      get 'edit_times'
      put 'update_billing'
      get 'new_911'
    end
```

rake routes:
  new_911_call GET    /calls/:id/new_911(.:format)        calls#new_911

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the parameter to the route. You're using a member route so you need to add the id parameter, take a look of [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). You may need to change that route.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I was using a member instead of a collection.  Also using new_911 gave me a constant error so I changed it to EmergencyCalls for my controller schema and utilized the normal "new" action.  Added resources :emergency_calls to my routes file and it worked.

Sorry for the goof.